# How would I know if the thread is a joinable thread ?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, detach, pthread-join

I'm new with multi-threading and I need to know when exactly do I need to join my thread not to detach it. what are the factors I need to take in consideration to know that the thread is  "must to join" ?

Answer (score 2):

- Use join if you want to wait block until the thread completes.
- Use detach if want let the thread to run independently.

You can also look at these answers

- [Detached vs. Joinable POSIX threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756882/detached-vs-joinable-posix-threads)
- [when to detach or join a boost thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527427/when-to-detach-or-join-a-boost-thread)
- [Do I must detach or join a pthread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429481/do-i-must-detach-or-join-a-pthread)